# Without mysql stored procedure or udf

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, stored-procedures, redash

I am trying to implement a mysql query for some report and can't figure it out.
Let's say we have a `'companies'` table, a `'users'` and a `'company_users'`.
The requested result set is:
 `'company_name', 'active_users', 'date'`(lets say 30 days back).
So I have to calculate user counts up to date based on `users.created_at`.
I could use some help to achieve it without stored procedure because I'll need to join the result set with another table.
Thank you.

Comment: What have you tried so far? And why the rails tag, are you doing this in mysql or activerecord?

Comment: The rails tag is my mistake. It is a mysql question. What I did so far is created a 30 dates result set. looped over it and calculated the count of 'active' users up to that date. I already achieved the expected result using a sub query instead of a fancy loop. Thanks.